# How to easily get -10V and 170V

Tags: arduino, dc, lcd, dc-dc-converter

I have just managed to control an old LCD of type TLX-1013-E0 using an arduino. I would now like to use it for a project. But it needs -10V for the contrast and 170V for the background lighting.

Could anyone suggest a nice way of creating these from a small 5V source. Both obviously won't have a big load.

Cheers 
Chris

Comment: Current for each? Is the 170V for an EL backlight or what?

Comment: Yes it is. I assume a couple mA. I don't have exact figures at the moment. I would make measurements as soon  as I need them for the design.

Comment: EL needs AC, BTW.

Comment: Oh, does it? This gets complicated then. Maybe the best thing would be an old fashioned transformer design.

Comment: You should probably do a search for "EL Display Driver". There are quite a few circuits out there which will generate the high voltage (usually 200-1kHz (?) frequency) from a 5V DC supply, either using a little transformer or resonance type circuits.

Comment: Look for old scanners which use EL tubes. Those are the high ones (8 cm high or so). Most of them have a small transformer + oscillator near the tube on the carriage. They generate 100 kHz or so, in order not to interfere with the scan.

Answer (score 1):

OK the previously mentioned pump could give the neg 10V so here are some ways of getting 170 V DC.

Firstly you could use a ZVS Royer Oscillator, that's a simple two-transistor circuit  The sinewave output could be rectified with cheap BAV21 diodes and no output choke is needed due to the small current demand.The ZVS Royer is sometimes called a "Tuned collector oscillator".

The ZVS Royer is widely used in low voltage fluorescent lamps and is good with cheap BJTs.

The output volts aren't regulated, but if the oscillator is run off 5V you should get pretty stable 170VDC with appropriate transformer.

Secondly if you don't want to build a transformer, then it's feasible to boost convert using an off-the-shelf SMD coil. The trick here is to reduce the switching losses and use a diode pump to do part of the job.

I managed to run a Valve car radio tuner section making 220 VDC this way. NO heatsinks, but a small die-cast Aluminium box to have no birdies on weak stations was needed when on bench.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone:

At least for the contrast voltage I have a solution: A charge pump. See the schematic ... 
The voltage source is a PWM-Pin of the micro controller (arduino).

[image: Charge Pump]

Comment: You may be able to put one of your stages through a transformer in order to get the 170VAC from it.

Comment: Note that the output of a "[Cockroft-Walton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator)" multiplier is DC. LCD backlight may want AC. With each stage, current decreases dramatically, transformer necessary first.